# pushsharp throwing an ambiguous error when trying to send apple notifications

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications

these are the only exception details that I can see:

> PushSharp.Apple.NotificationFailureException: Exception of type
>   'PushSharp.Apple.NotificationFailureException' was thrown.

when I run the method to actually queue up the notifications from my development desktop, it works fine.  It only starts to fail when I publish the code to my server.  What's interesting is that it worked fine on the server for about 2 weeks and then just stopped working.  I'll admit I've made some changes to lots of pieces of code in this application, but nothing that would rock the boat with the apple notifications.  Unfortunately I can't get any more details about the exception nor why it's being thrown on the server.  I tried to ramp up elmah on this application, but elmah isn't even firing when the exception is thrown.  I"m also not seeing a YSOD, I'm only able to see the exception when I view the logs generated by NLog.

anyone have any ideas here?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out one of the iOS device tokens was bad.  I'm still not sure why my loop is bombing out as a result of one notification failure, but that is what the cause is.

pushsharp could really use some better exception handling.

Comment: I know this is really old, but in case someone finds it: in recent versions you can now call .ToString() on the notificationFailureException to get a full error description.